# Custom Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex

How is it possible to use regex to separate

```
BCT34385Z0000N07518Z
BCT34395Z0000N07518Z
```

into `BCT343` format? I am using this for magento to break 2 types of serial number ie  `BCT34385Z0000N07518Z` and `BCT34395Z0000N07518Z` into regex to just identified the first 6 characters ie `BCT343`.

Comment: What is BCT343 format? What output do you expect? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you want to grab only the first 6 characters?

Comment: If it has one, give us a link to the format spec. If not, you should at least explain the structure of that thing. How should we know what your criteria are, otherwise?

Comment: @Atropo Yes i want to grab the first 6 characters

Comment: Why don't you just substring the input? Which language are you using?

Comment: @XaviLópez php scripting

Comment: Give us more infos like: language, OS you're using. For the first 6 characters you don't need a regexp, a substring would be enough.

Comment: Then why not just [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)? Like `$value = substr("BCT34385Z0000N07518Z", 0, 6);`

Comment: @Atropo i want to create two arrays -- BCT343 and the rest

Comment: @danny - Then suggest saying so. We are not very good at reading peoples minds. Just do two `substr()` calls. Also, what language are we talking about?

Comment: @elusive for php to use regex in magento

Comment: @Danny, please edit in all these details you've provided in the question. The information you're giving here in comments is relevant, and the question text as it is now is turning out to be quite unclear.

Comment: @danny you should rewrite your question. Explain what do you want to obtain, what language you're using, don't keep on write comments. Write a good question!

Comment: `array(substr($code, 0, 6), substr($code, 6))` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **very bad practice**, but because you asked for it:

```php
$str = 'BCT34385Z0000N07518Z';
preg_match('/^(.{6})(.*?)$/', $str, $result);

echo $result[1]; // 'BCT343'
echo $result[2]; // '85Z0000N07518Z'
```

or if you want an if statement:

```php
$str = ...;

if (preg_match('/^BCT343/', $str)) {
    // yes!
}
```

Comment: is it possible to get the 2 results in using regex?

Comment: @danny I use 1 regex and get 2 results?

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is to split those strings in two parts (the first six characters and the rest) you don't need regex at all. You can do it with just [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
<?php
    $str1 = substr("BCT34385Z0000N07518Z", 0, 6); // BCT343
    $str2 = substr("BCT34385Z0000N07518Z", 6); // 85Z0000N07518Z
?>
```

If you wanted to do this with a regex, you should set up two capture groups, one for the first six characters, and another one for the rest of the string. The regular expression would look like:

```
/^(.{6})(.*)$/

/^                // Start of input
(                 // Start capture group 1
  .               // Any charactger
  {6}             // Repeated exactly 6 times
)                 // End of capture group 1
(                 // Start capture group 1
  .               // Any character
  *               // Repeated 0 or more times
)                 // End of capture group 2
$/                // End of input
```

and you should use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to utilize it. Remember that each capture group will be in a position of the match array. See an example of the regex at this [RegExr](http://regexr.com?34cjb).

Comment: need it in regex format. I cant use this on magento since it expecting in regex